# Nodejs sequelize reader/writer async actions

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm looking for a solution for asynchronous actions on nodejs -> sequelize (mysql)

I have an endpoint (a webhook) that receives messages, and does the following:

[1]

sequelize.query(FIND IF MESSAGE EXISTS...)

[2]

if [1] doesn't exists, conversationsModel.create(....) and return
'X' otherwise return 'Y' (without creating the object)

and what I experience is that I have like a "race" between my reader/writer.

I found some references saying that "transactions" could help in that case, but if we are not in the same request context (different incoming API requests) - should it help anyway?

** note that for the "read" action I'm using inline query:

`SELECT xxx FROM conversations where context="yyy" AND phoneNumber=:phoneNumber AND createdAt LIKE :time`,`

and for the "write" action I use sequelize model:

`await conversationsModel.create({phoneNumber: to.phoneNumber,context: "team",displayName: "xxx",externalId,message,type: "media",});`

can you guys suggest a proper solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good instance of when to use the `.upsert` static method in `sequelize` (see [the docs here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-upsert)).  Here's
[a link](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html#-code-model-upsert----code-) to the manual.  There would have to be a unique or primary key on the `Conversation` model in `sequelize` in order to use this method.  For example, suppose there's a unique index on the `context` and `phoneNumber` attributes.  Then the upsert statement would be something like,

```
let [instance, created] = await ConversationsModel.upsert({
        phoneNumber: to.phoneNumber,
        context: "team",
        displayName: "xxx",
        externalId,
        message,
        type: "media",
    })

if (created) {
    // New conversation instance was created in database...
    //  Access the instance here...
} else {
    // New conversation instance was not created in database,
    //  but the existing instance was updated...
    //  Access the instance here...
}
```

*Important note:*  As pointed out in the links above, the value for `created` is only set to a non-null value when using `MySQL` or `MSSQL`, but since the original question states `MySQL` is being used, this solution should suffice.

*Disclaimer:*  If the `select` statement and the `insert/update` statement are truly being done in separate api requests, then there is no way to avoid a race condition without having the two requests communicate with each other in some way.  Perhaps the client program may have some mechanism for communication between separate requests, to avoid communicating through the database some way.